# java proxy pass requests to upstream applications

Tags: java, spring

I want to write a Java controller that does proxy (reverse) pass requests to upstream applications. The requests could be get/post or even multipart (file uploads). I'm thinking of something similar to what happens in web servers like Nginx or Apache. My question is are there any utilities/libraries readily available?
Also, I would like to understand its internal working. Does it fire a new HTTP request to the upstream application, while holding onto the original HTTP request Or does it simply deep copy everything from the original request to the upstream one? Or does it work at lower layers of HTTP/TCP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't asking a  question.

Comment: Oops missed to add the question - this is my first question on SOF. Have edited the question now

Comment: Your question is still too broad. SO isn't really the place to ask for recommendations, and questions should only include one thing you're asking about, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a Java-based proxy service you can try Zuul API gateway. Check it [on this guide by Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/) and [in this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_zuul_proxy_server_and_routing.htm).

Comment: Thanks for being so understanding and answering it and providing pointers. ZUUL got my task done. For other questions, I will deep dive into it to understand it myself. I have accepted your answer as it exactly does what I was looking for.